# Псевдоэлемент last-child. Как применить к последнему блоку?

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="single_address">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            <h4>Адрес</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="single_address">
            <a href="tel:+74999777777">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            <h4>Телефон</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="single_address">
            <a href="mailto:info@domain.ru?subject=Тема вашего письма">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            <h4>Email</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="single_address">
            <a class="f_telegram" href="tg://resolve?domain=telegram">
            <i class="fa fa-telegram"></i>
            <h4>Telegram</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: к блоку `col` ?

Comment: К <div class="single_address">

Comment: В стилях прописано
.single_address { margin: 0 0 15px 0;}

Хотел что бы к последнему элементу .single_address не применялся margin: 0 0 15px 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Описание :last-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/last-child)

```
.main :last-child .single_address{
  /* нужные стили */
}
```

Comment: .main :last-child .single_address {
    margin: 0;
}

Так тоже сработало.

Comment: Убрал div[class^="col"]

Comment: @SanZH да, так тоже можно